# How can i define a method in a class that it return only part of the class

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

sorry for my poor english; I'll show you the code;

```
class Service {
  word: string = "hi"
  get actions(): { hello: Function, greet: Function } {
    return this
  }
}
class TestService extends Service {
  hello() {}
  greet() {}
}
enter code here
const service = new TestService()
service.hello() // good
console.log(service.word) // error
```

how can i define a type that can makes actions only return all the Function properties? this might be a little confused, please notice that actions define in parent class, but i want its type are Part of inherit class's property

sorry for my poor description, i just update my code

Comment: `type PartialService = Omit<Service, "word">;`?

Comment: sorry for my poor description, i just update my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that should not be visible outside the class can be hidden using `private`/`protected`:

```
abstract class Service
{
    private word: string = "hi"

    // These would be required, otherwise `return this` is an error in `actions`.
    abstract hello(): void;
    abstract greet(): void;

    get actions(): { hello: Function, greet: Function }
    {
        return this
    }
}
class TestService extends Service
{
    hello() { }
    greet() { }
}

const service = new TestService()
service.hello() // good
console.log(service.word) // error
```

As long as you are using classes directly you *always get the full interface of the class*. If you want to restrict the type more dynamically you probably need to work with functions returning interfaces/advanced types.

e.g.

```
type FunctionKeys<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? K : never
}[keyof T]

function createService()
{
    class Service
    {
        word: string = "hi"
    
        hello() { }
        greet() { }
    
        get actions(): { hello: Function, greet: Function }
        {
            return this
        }
    }

    // Restricts the type to only the functions of Service
    const service: Pick<Service, FunctionKeys<Service>> = new Service();

    return service;
}


const service = createService()
service.hello() // good
console.log(service.word) // error
```

In this example, if a function is added to the `Service` class, it will automatically become available on the constructed instance.

Comment: please tell me more about the dynamic type part

Comment: @frankw: I added an example for more dynamic typing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use class inheritance. Find more [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-inherit-a-class-in-typescript)

Make a subclass of the class `Service`, and make `Service` class extend the subclass.

```
    class Service extends SubclassService {
      word: string = "hi"
    }
    class Subclass {
      hello() {}
      greet() {}
      get actions(): { hello: Function, greet: Function } {
        return this
      }
    }

    const service = new SubclassService()
    service.hello() // good
    console.log(service.word) // error
```

Comment: sorry for my poor description, i just update my code